# Include timestamp in vala log message

Tags: logging, glib, vala

I have a lot of debug(...) and info(...) logging in my vala application code and I'm trying to add timestamps in the logging.

I am avoiding the set_writer_func as it requires glib "2.50" and eOS Loki is at glib 2.48. The MVCE below kind of gives me the right output format but I cannot set the log level i.e. setting the level as INFO should not output the DEBUG messages.

Thanks in advance for any help / pointers on this.

```
public class LogTest {
    public static int main(string[] args) {
        Environment.set_variable ("G_MESSAGES_DEBUG", "all", true);
        Log.set_default_handler(
            (domain, level, message) => {
                domain = "My.Domain";
                level = GLib.LogLevelFlags.LEVEL_INFO;
                print("[%s] [%s] %s\n", Time.local(time_t()).to_string(), level.to_string(), message);
            }
        );

        debug("logging debug");
        info("logging info");
        warning("logging warning");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This gives the following output, I was not expecting debug to show up.

```
[2018-02-16 23:14:53] [G_LOG_LEVEL_INFO] logging.vala:12: logging debug
[2018-02-16 23:14:53] [G_LOG_LEVEL_INFO] logging.vala:13: logging info
[2018-02-16 23:14:53] [G_LOG_LEVEL_INFO] logging.vala:14: logging warning
```

---

Granite.Services.Logger seems to be having what I want, so will go with it for the moment. Adding the MVCE here just in case it benefits someone.

```
using Granite.Services;
public class LogTest {
    public static int main(string[] args) {
        Environment.set_variable ("G_MESSAGES_DEBUG", "all", true);

        Logger.initialize("My.Domain");
        Logger.DisplayLevel = LogLevel.INFO;

        debug("logging debug");
        info("logging info");
        warning("logging warning");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compile with valac --pkg=granite logging.vala and then run:

```
[INFO 12:44:33.454785] logging.vala:26: logging info
[WARNING 12:44:33.454839] logging.vala:27: logging warning
```

Answer (score 1):

The code to handle filtering based on `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG` is part of [the default log handler](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Log.default_handler.html); if you implement a custom handler it's up to you to also filter messages based on whatever settings you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update. How can I change the logging for the default log handler (I thought I was doing the same in the Log.set_default_handler function call above). Also, what am I doing wrong in the above code to not suppress the debug logs. Alternatively, how can I filter messages to add the timestamp into the logging.

Comment: I have added a solution using granite library. It seems to produce the logging with timestamp that I wanted

Comment: `Log.set_default_handler` will set the default log handler, but the default implementation of the default log handler (*i.e.*, `Log.default_handler`) is where the logic I'm talking about resides. In other words, if you change the default log handler to a custom function (like you're doing) you need to reproduce any filtering logic you need.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was not able to find a filtering function for the default_handler - is it the writer_default. If yes, I will give it a try later when glib version is 2.50 in my distro

Comment: You have to write your own filtering function, GLib's is in the function you're trying to replace. Filtering messages in the application isn't something that's usually done, unless you're simply writing to stdout/stderr (like GLib is). Usually the custom handler is used to log to some other service (syslog, journald, or something like stackdriver) and any filtering would be done downstream, so glib's approach makes sense.